# What is @apply in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm curious what the CSS directive `@apply` does. I have googled `@apply` but I couldn't find anything that could explain its meaning properly for me.

What is the usage of such a directive?

Comment: https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/ Some useful reading possibly

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The simple way of explaining it would be; introducing variables into CSS (which is a feature of preprocessors, such as [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29)), and mixins which are function like behaviors (also in preprocessors).

Imagine that `--header-theme` is a function (mixin):

```
:root {
  --header-theme: {
    color: red;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: 600;
  };
}

h1 {
  @apply --header-theme;
}


h2 {
  @apply --header-theme;
}
```

This way, you can use it in many different places without having to rewrite it again ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Now the variable part could be explained with this example:

```
:root {
  --brand-color: red; /* Default value */
  --header-theme: {
    color: var(--brand-color);
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: 600;
  };
}

h1 {
  @apply --header-theme;
}


h2 {
  --brand-color: green;
  @apply --header-theme;
}
```

The mixin will have a variable sent to it and change the color.

This is not the limits of the feature, and you can use it for far more. You can read more about mixin and variables in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide) for other ways of using it, and after I suggest you read [this blog post](https://pawelgrzybek.com/css-mixins-with-apply-rule/).

Now after I got you excited, it is time for the bad news. It is not implemented in browsers yet ([Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5753701012602880)), but it is still worth knowing that it is coming and maybe if you want to prepare yourself start with Sass.

Comment: does the var function serve the same purpose in SASS as in javascript? Sorry, I don't know any SASS.

Comment: the variable is somehow the same control all from one location instead of rewriting, the function is a little bit different, but it serve the same general idea, what I am trying to say; for now you won't be able to use it anyway; so if you feel curious about the feature check sass (ruby) or less (node.js), that where they came up with the idea

Comment: The spec author's blog post titled "Why I Abandoned @apply" suggests that this feature will _NOT_ be making its way into future browsers.

Spec as I found it - https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/#intro
Retraction over at - http://www.xanthir.com/b4o00

Comment: This was a very brief but detailed explanation. Thank you for such a useful answer! I am coming from a SASs background but starting to use tailwind css for the first time.

Comment: @user1645942: And now it says *"Removed"* (`Feature: CSS @apply Rule (Removed)`).

Comment: Related: *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Comment: [Eric Willigers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css/52639159#52639159) is somewhat more up-to-date.

Answer (score 39):

`@apply` is from [a proposal](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/) that has [since been abandoned](https://www.xanthir.com/b4o00), and replaced with [CSS Shadow Parts](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts/).

> the @apply rule, which allows an author to store a set of properties
> in a named variable, then reference them in other style rules.

Comment: Unfortunate... CSS Shadow Parts serves a completely different utility: it allows to work with native shadow DOM in a similar way as to normal DOM. While the `@apply` was just some shorthand for a set of styles, helping us to write DRY code without using post-processors.

Comment: `@apply` is **not** replaced by _CSS Shadow Parts_. They are two CSS specs that have nothing in common.

Answer (score 35):

[Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) uses this as a special directive.

Tailwind's `@apply` is kind of like a super-class.  You can list other classes that should *apply* to this rule.  I think of it as a way to group classes together that are often found together.

Comment: Is it a part of CSS though, or is this something Tailwind's pre-processor handles.

Comment: @Qasim The tailwind pre-processor. "Directives are custom Tailwind-specific at-rules you can use in your CSS that offer special functionality for Tailwind CSS projects."

Answer (score 22):

`@apply` basically allows you to reuse CSS blocks without having to copy them around and without having to modify their selectors.

It will make it easier to use CSS frameworks and keep semantic class names at the same time.

I found [this article](https://hashnode.com/post/creating-native-css-mixins-with-apply-rule-cinh1j54c01hla153n9x73770) to be a nice instruction to this feature.

Unfortunately, at the moment, browser support is basically [non-existent](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40apply). It can be used with a CSS pre-processor such as [PostCSS](https://github.com/pascalduez/postcss-apply).

It's future is also uncertain, if I understand well. The main advocate behind this feature [stopped supporting it](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/needed-new-champion-for-css-apply-rule/2012).

Comment: ikr! I love the way I can use these classes from Tailwind CSS in `@apply`. That introduces exceptionally new way of working with stylesheet that leaves you with reusable bricks, which are also easily categorized - you can actually sort them (you can use reference for this like me from ToC of Tailwind CSS documentation) and not properties anymore to scan stylesheets efficiently! There are a lot of possibilities like writing simple `pin` shothand instead of all `top/bottom/left/right: 0`.