# WebPack / Method of replicating Tailwind CSS's @apply directive to move away from @extend in SASS

Tags: css, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I'm working on an internal CSS 'framework' / methodology that sits somewhere between ITCSS and Tailwind.

We use alot of utility classes, but sometimes the actual class name gets too long and we wish to extract it into its own class.

Here's a pseudo example:

```
<button class="p-2 bg-primary elevate-1">Click Me</button
```

What I wish to do:

```
.btn {
    @extend .p-2;
    @extend .bg-primary;
    @extend .elevate-1;
}
```

I know that @extend should be avoided so wish to not use that method.

Is there a webpack plugin that allows you to use @extend without the issues?

Or, does anyone know how Adam Wathan has created the @apply directive: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components/#extracting-utility-patterns-with-apply

Taken from the docs, he can do this:

```
.btn-blue {
    @apply bg-blue text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}
```

Is this a SASS function he's written, if so any information on how to create similar?

Thanks.

Comment: that is not possible, yet

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind uses [PostCSS](https://postcss.org/) to do CSS transformations.

See [What is @apply in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css) for more context.