# Nuxt Js not compiling all CSS rules

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

My dev environment is working great, but when I tried building the app, some of the styles are missing. Here is an example

```
<style lang="scss">
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  @apply tw-bg-border tw-text-primary tw-font-bold;

  &--danger {
    color: white;
    @apply tw-bg-danger-alt;
  }
  &--info {
    color: white;
    @apply tw-bg-info;
  }
  &--warning {
    color: white;
    @apply tw-bg-warning;
  }
}

.badge--success {
  color: white;
  @apply tw-bg-success-alt;
}
</style>
```

I need to move .badge--success outside for it to work, but all other CSS modifiers are not working.

Comment: What do you want to do in fact? `@apply` is a css rules to use with css variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css/52639159 .
In scss, you should use @extend or @mixin: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I am using tailwind hence the @apply directive. the problem is .badge--info, .badge--danger etc. are not compiling when yung yarn build