# How to use @Apply from tailwind in plain CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) in a React project.

I call classes in this way :

```
<p className="text-gray-600 text-base-14">
        <Link to="/code">{props.name}</Link>
</p>
```

In fact sometimes I need many classes ( 15 -20 ) and It's not good practice to write them in JS file.

In [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) I was using in :

```
 <style type="postcss">
   .prg{
     @apply text-gray-600;
     @apply text-base-14;
   }
   </style>
```

Then I use the class `prg` in the component ( Vue component )

I tried the same on React but it does not work!

```
 <p className="prg">
            <Link to="/code">{props.name}</Link>
        </p>
```

What's the issue?

Comment: What front-end framework are you using? Is this React.js?

Comment: `@apply` is not a part of standard CSS, it requires a CSS preprocessor (such as SASS): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css/52639159

Comment: Is there a way to call these classes in standalone CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

As of the [tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components#extracting-css-components-with-apply), if you want to use custom classes based on Tailwind classes, add them to your global CSS file (where your @tailwind directives are).

Comment: Could you provide a tangible example ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a utility class to your `src/index.css` file like this:

```css
.prg{
    @apply text-gray-600;
    @apply text-base-14;
}
```