# Tailwind css apply on new class does not work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to add a new color in the tailwind-CSS config.

And use that new color as background inside of class.

But I am getting the error:

```
// index.scss
// Here I am trying to apply green-100 as a background color
.focus-unanswered-question {
  @apply: bg-green-100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```

As a result of this code I am getting the next error message:

> Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.

```
    // tailwind.config.js
    module.exports = {
      theme: {
        },
        colors: {
          transparent: 'transparent',
          black: '#000',
          white: '#FFF',
          status: {
            yellow: '#ffbf29',
            red: '#cc2a18',
          },
          green: {
            100: '#fbfcfc',
          },
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you should have a colon after `apply`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css.

Comment: omg, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Remove `:` after `@apply`

```js
.focus-unanswered-question {
  @apply bg-green-100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```