# Native css mixins dont work with styled components (@apply)?

Tags: css, styled-components, mixins

@apply directive just doesn't work when used inside a styled component's css :o

Global css file:

```
--red-var: red;
--blue-mixin: {
 color: blue;
}
```

Local styled component:

```
const Some = styled.div`
 color: var(--red-var); // Working fine
 @apply --blue-mixin; // Nothing changed
`;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply-in-css may this help? (:root needed)

Comment: :root doesnt help, actually mixin was initially declared on :root level

Comment: Well, "@apply" in css is abandoned according to https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_part

You can use "@extend" from SCSS or the same plugin from postcss